# mvc entity framework : login using a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, entity-framework-4.1, login-control, loginview

I have created a database in Microsoft sql server express. I need to be able to login on Mvc 2 app, using my database ( not the one existing on AcountController meaning MembershipService )

I just need to replace MemeberAhipService with my database. How can I do that ( i'm using entity framework code first ) . I don't need to create a model in visual studio. I have the usermodel, userContext: Db . I think i need repository also. Can anyone show me an example, of tell me the steps ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own MembershipService.

Example:

New MembershipService.cs (or whatever you want)

```
public class MembershipService
{
    public bool IsUserValid(string username, string password)
    {
         var db = new DatabaseContext();
         var user = db.GetUser(username, password);
         // Or however you want to get your data, via Context or Repository
         return (user != null); 
    }
}
```

New FormsClass.cs

```
public class FormService
{
     public void SignIn(string username, List<string> roles)
     {

            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new
                            FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,            // Version
                            username,                               // Username
                            DateTime.Now,                           // Creation
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),            // Expiration
                            false,                                  // Persistent
                            string.Join(",", roles.ToArray()));     // Roles

            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));

            GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(username);
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles.ToArray());
     }
}
```

In Global.asax:

```
        protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                string encTicket = authCookie.Value;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encTicket))
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encTicket);
                    FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
                    var roles = ticket.UserData.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    GenericPrincipal prin = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                    HttpContext.Current.User = prin;

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: thx a lot. I will try doing that. I am new in mvc also entity framework. Do u have some links where i can read more about repository or doing something like login from database?

Comment: Then  public IMembershipService MembershipService { get; set; } will become just: public MembershipService { get; set; }

Comment: Then  **public IMembershipService MembershipService { get; set; }** will become just: **public MembershipService { get; set; }** . In this class we will have the properties ** username** , ** password**?

Comment: You can just create an interface for MembershipService to inherit from, you can have a property called Username, I'd advise against using a Password as a property

Comment: Sorry for keep asking. Just one more question, please. The DatabaseContext from yout example should look like this: **public DbSet<User> LogonUser { get; set; }** where in **Class User I have the 2 properties : **username, password** .  The property **GetUser** with what should be populated? I would be really gratefull if u may help

Comment: I need to wrap the project in a class library. How can i do that? In models i have **class users** with properties name, id. i have a class database 

`public class UserData : DbContext
    {   public DbSet<Users> LogonUser { get; set; }`

 and class **UserRepository**. 
I have created new project class library. what should i put in it? I need to put class UserData and class Users?